# Objective-C : UIButton image does not changes

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am doing this to change the `UIButton` image, here all **"switches"** are `IBOutlets` of `UIButton`,

```
-(IBAction)userselect:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *btnTagcatcher =(UIButton * )sender;
 if(btnTagcatcher.tag == 1)
    {
        if(btnimgflag1 == 0)
            {
                NSString* path  = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"check-box-withtick-1n1" 
                                                                  ofType:@"png"];
                UIImage *image  = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
                [switch1 setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                NSString* path1  = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"check-box-withouttickn1" 
                                                                   ofType:@"png"];
                UIImage *image1  = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path1];
                [switch2 setImage:image1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [switch3 setImage:image1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [switch4 setImage:image1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                btnimgflag2 = 0;
                btnimgflag3 = 0;
                btnimgflag4 = 0;


                btnimgflag1 = 1;
            }
            else if(btnimgflag1 == 1)
            {
        NSString* path  = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"check-box-withouttickn1" 
                                                                  ofType:@"png"];
                UIImage *image  = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

                //[switch1 setImage: image];
                [switch1 setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                btnimgflag1 = 0;
            }
```

But some times **(usually when pressed first time)** the button image does not changes when tapped.

I have no idea, what is going on here, plz. Guide me in this, thanx in advance.

Regards Saad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you change this condition `else if(btnimgflag1 == 1)` to simple `else` statement. Because in the `if` part you are assigning btnimgflag1 to be 1 `btnimgflag1 = 1;`. Just my guess, and I had exactly the same problem!! If that didn’t help out!! `IBOutlet connections` should be the problem!!

Answer (score 1):

Please Debug your code and check either you are getting the right tag of a button. I have implemeted exactly what you described and copy paste you code, it won't work, then I just changed the `if(btnTagcatcher.tag == 1)` to `if(btnTagcatcher.tag == 0)`. Now it's working, please try verify this.

If event this you have a problem, then please send me your email id, I will send you complete code.